# Poor performance of lwuit list on Nokia C3

Tags: java-me, lwuit

My lwuit app works fine with a touch screen phone emulator provided by java microedition 3.0. My lists scroll great.

However, when I installed the app on Nokia C3  I had scrolling issues with lists.

My list has around 300 elements. And the scrolling was quite slow and trouble some. It was not as smooth as the device's native scrolling capability (I tried scrolling the contacts on that phone and the scrolling was pretty decent).

What can i do to make lists scroll more effortlessly and smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

It is very important to know how do you build this list. Are you using a `ListModel`to manage the data element in the list? Are you using a `CustomRender`? Please, give more information about your code.

Take a look in this blog to have more info:

http://lwuit.blogspot.com.es/2008/07/lwuit-list-renderer-by-chen-fishbein.html

http://lwuit.blogspot.com.es/2010/12/lwuit-resource-editor-tutorial-part-6.html

http://lwuit.blogspot.com.es/2011/04/contain-that-list-bringing-containers.html

Comment: hi, I am using the list model which is mention in the article here. --> http://lwuit.blogspot.in/2008/06/lightweight-text-input-in-lwuit.html  you have probably already read this article. The only thing i have done is that I have used vector to initialize the list (The article uses an array of strings.)

Comment: I don't get you. What are you trying to say?